# Mustache renders actual HTML tags in the dom?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, mustache

I have a simple mustache function that grabs a template, process it and then I use $().append to insert it where I need to.

The problem is it actually renders the html tags instead of just the text.

Instead of :

```
paragraph1...
paragraph2...
```

It does (actually shows the html tags):

```
<p>paragraph1</p>
<p>paragraph2</p>
```

My Mustache function:

```
$.get(baseUrl+"js_temp/template.html", function(templates) {
     tab.append(Mustache.render(templates, templateData));
});
```

template.html:

```
<div>
{{content}}
</div>
```

Pretty standard stuff... and it worked fine up until about 2 days ago... and I can't figure out what I could have done to cause this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of why this might be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: you obviously did not have `p` tags, two days ago, in your content :)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps try using 3 `{{{content}}}`?

> All variables are HTML-escaped by default. If you want to render unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: `{{{name}}}`. You can also use & to unescape a variable.

I got this on the git repo for mustache.